# Why does PHP 5.3.10 (fcgi) choke on this line?

Tags: php

Why does PHP 5.3.10 (fcgi) choke on this line?

```
<? echo $dadosboleto["ponto_venda"]." <img src='imagens/b.png' width=10 height=1> ".$tmp2?>
```

Comment: Is it throwing an error?

Comment: whats in `$dadosboleto` and `$tmp2`?

Comment: Need more information, what are the values of your variables? Have you turned on error_reporting? What error if any is being displayed?? Repeating the title of the question in the actual question itself, does not help to answer ANY of these items.

Comment: We need more information. Seriously, what do you expect us to do Gaia?

Comment: Do you have [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) set to 1?  Try replacing `<?` with `<?php`.

Comment: @Rocket nailed it, thank you. If you submit an answer I will accept it.

Comment: To all the people that are voting this question down: it turns out that there IS enough information here to solve the problem: see accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for undownvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code starts with `<?`, for that to work, you need [`short_tag_open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) set to 1.  Otherwise, you need to use `<?php`.

Answer (score 0):

not saying that this would be the solution - since indeed there could be other code involved.. but first of all I would rather prefer one of either a-bit-cleaner ways of writing that line of code:

1) 
`<?PHP echo($dadosboleto['ponto_venda']." <img src='imagens/b.png' width='10' height='1'> ".$tmp2); ?>`

2) 
`<?PHP echo($dadosboleto['ponto_venda']); ?>> <img src='imagens/b.png' width='10' height='1'> <?PHP echo($tmp2); ?>`

..hope this points in some direction..

ps: and be careful with double (") and single (') not getting mixed up